# Find largest digit palindrome - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, palindrome

I am trying to solve a problem based on palindrome.
But all I keep getting is this exception - `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I really wanted to figure it out myself, but I'm not able to understand the cause.

Here's the code:

```
public class LargestPalindrome
{
    public int isPalindrome(int n)
    {
        int revNum=0;
        int num=n,flag=0;
        while(num!=0)
        {
            revNum=revNum*10;
            revNum=revNum + (num%10);
            num=num/10;
        }

        if(n==revNum)
            flag=1;
        else
            flag=0;
        return(flag);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LargestPalindrome p=new LargestPalindrome();
        int flag=0,pro=0;
        int a[]= new int[100];
        int b[]=new int[100];

        for(int i=1;i<=99;i++)
        {
            a[i]=i;
            b[i]=i;
        }

        for(int i=1;i<=99;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=99;i++)
            {
                pro=a[i]*b[j];

                flag=p.isPalindrome(pro);
                if(flag==1)
                    System.out.println(pro);
                pro=0;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

***Any suggestions?***

Comment: `i` and `j` looks very similar, sometimes I use `x` and `y` ;) I've just noticed that they're similar two :/

Comment: Thanks Maroun Maroun I'm really feeling very embarrassed on my such a stupid mistake. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @Shashank I tried to rewrite your solution a little bit, and simplify counting logic. Here is solution [LargestNumberPalindrome](http://pastebin.com/CTzHWRdc).

Comment: Thanks @nazar_art your program really makes the job much simpler :D... thanks once again.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(int i=1;i<=99;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=99;i++)
```

You should increment j in the second for statement.

Comment: Easy one to miss. +1